# Ubuntu Phone BQ Aquaris: Color change?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, themes

Is there a way to change the color theme of the phone? I did find an background option, but this only replaces the unlock screen on my phone. I must admit I am a sworn enemy of white, and the Ubuntu pre-installed on the BQ Aquaris has WAY too much white.

I also could not find any themes or other color change indicating software in the store.